# can an form element <input type=file > take an online image as value?

Tags: html, forms

for example value="http://imgur/someimage"

Comment: perhaps i should clarify, i am using the open graph api to supplement my registration system .. the api coneects and fetched all user information including a link to the picture..

Comment: oops.. pressed enter.. so anyways.. i get a link to the profile picture ..but my registration system uses an <input file> to take the pic and store it in mysql. how can i replace the input file to take the data from facebook instead.. if, as you suggested i try to do it server side facebook authentication will create problems..

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to save the file locally before you can upload it.

Comment: of course, you can also leave the file on its original location and store only the url. If that is sufficient of course

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Yes, but you can't use an `<input type=file>` for that.

Comment: perhaps i should clarify, i am using the open graph api to supplement my registration system .. the api coneects and fetched all user information including a link to the picture...but my registration system uses an <input file> to take the pic and store it in mysql. how can i replace the input file to take the data from facebook instead.. if, as you suggested i try to do it server side facebook authentication will create problems.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it can't.

You would have to make it a text input, and fetch the image on server side.